# Ajax form posting without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

Okay so I've tried this for quite a while now. For some reason everytime I hit the Submit button the page refreshes. What do I need to change?

```
<script>
$('#submit').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({

  url: 'likesystem.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: $('#like').serialize(),

});
});
</script>
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form method='post' action='likesystem.php' id='like'>
<input class='form-control' type='hidden' value='$row[0]' name='postid'> //I have made a sql request to show me the id of a post in the database
<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' name='like' id='submit'>Send</button>
</form>
```

Now I tried changing the buttons type from 'submit' to 'button' but that didn't help.
The page refreshes when I set the button to 'submit' and then it all works but the page reloads. If I set it to 'button' then nothing happens at all.

My goal is for the form to be posted to a php file where the post id $row[0] is then used to update a database entry.

Now I know there are similar question already asked but noe of the answers could help me.

Thanks for any replies.

EDIT:
I don't know if this is helpful or not but it won't hurt so:
This is likesystem.php, where the submitted data is processed and a sql query made. @Lexxusss had a good answer however it caused some funny stuff in the database which led me to believe that there might be another problem with this code. (It does however work perfectly normal with page refresh, so...?)

```
<?php    

require_once 'config.php';

        $link = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);

        if(! $link ) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            echo "Connection Error";
        }

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {



    $postid = $_POST['postid'];




        $sql = "UPDATE posts SET poslike = poslike + 1 WHERE id = $postid";


if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    //echo "Success";
} else {
    //echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Comment: The id of your button is `submit`, not `like` and you're trying to use `$('#like')`

Comment: Oh I thought that had to be the form id there... Will try

Comment: Have you tried adding `return false` at the end of your on submit function?

Comment: Not necessary @Eyzi because he has `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Now I have changed $('#like') to $('#submit') -> page refreshes @JayBlanchard

Comment: Yeah, instead of trapping the form submission, capture the button click.

Comment: $('#submit').click(function() {....}); - what is wrong, sory ?

Comment: Button with `type="submit"` ALWAYS reload page. But you can stop propagation:

Comment: There's just so much false information here. 1. only forms have submit events. 2. type="submit" doesn't always reload the page. If you're listing to the submit event and preventing default, the page won't reload. 3. Binding to the click event rather than the submit event may work, but, it causes pressing enter on the form inputs to refresh the page, so it's only half a solution. 4. adding return false is useless if you're already preventing the default action.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to care about submit button, you need to care about form.

Try this:

```
<script>
$('#like').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({

  url: 'likesystem.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: $('#like').serialize(),

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: @D.Krold Why not? This would be the better way of handling your scenario.

Comment: because there are many strange things happening: 1. no post request at all, 2. two post requests at the same time despite the button being pressed only once 3. working but with redirection to likesystem.php. Why is it acting differently all the time?

Answer (score -1):

Just capture the button and handle the click on it:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({

    url: 'likesystem.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#like').serialize(),

  });

  event.stopPropagation();

});
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Okay weird things are happening: Sometimes the page refreshes, other times it doesn't.

Comment: I fixed the script for cases if the button can be generated outside the initial DOM - that might cause such weird things

Comment: Now this is good because the page won't refresh now, that is great, however, in my database it looks like the button was pressed three times instead of the one time i pressed it. Every time I press the button I send an sql query and increase a value in my databse by one. It was at 0 and after the button click at 3. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: hmm, yes, I understand. But does it really send request three times ? You can check it in you browser tool (network tab in console for Chrome and Mozilla). Also for any case, just to be sure - you can add: "event.stopPropaganation();" after ajax-call.

Comment: @Lexxusss by adding "event.stopPropaganation();" theres nothing happening again. No reload but no request either. Console says: TypeError: event.stopPropaganation is not a function

Comment: sorry - stopPropagation

Comment: It is actually posting it three times.. EDIT: make that 4. what is going on?

Comment: Yes I have changed the button type to "button"

Comment: seems there are some other binds to this button. You can also try `$('#like').on('submit'...` method. With propagation and `return false` at the end.